# Can't get rid of vertical margin in Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: buttons issues]

I've got an issue with the button on the right... **The round green one has some kind of vertical margin (in yellow) and I don't know how to get rid of it** and its making me crazy !

I would like it to be like the RaisedButton on the left.

This is the code that creates this :

```
Widget myWidget() {
    return Row (
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child:
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Container(child: Text("+")),
            )),
        Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child:ClipOval(
              child: Container(
                  child:InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState((){
                          
                        });
                      },
                      child: myButton("+")
                  )
              )
          ),
        ),
```

And the myButton widget :

```
Widget myButton(text) {
    return new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 0, bottom: 0), //horizontal margin works but vertical margin is not impacted by whatever I put here
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      child: new Text(text,
          style: new TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize:
              50.0)),
    );
  }
```

The parent widget :

```
return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Align(...),
            Align(...)
          ]
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Card(
            child: InputControlParent(),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
              myWidget() #<= child presented above
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Now what surprises me is that you gave it a `margin` property. If you don't want the `margin`, consider removing it ?

Comment: @void I want the vertical margin to go away but not the horizontal one. As you can see I set the vertical margin to 0 and its doing nothing. For some reasons, removing the horizontal margin does work. But that's not what I want :-)

Comment: can you draw i image, what you want, so that i can solve it.

Comment: Add code for the widget above the button

Comment: @ArshShaikh I edited the question with the parent widget ! thx

Comment: I did not downvote, but the reasons might be an perceived deviation from [ask]. Do you think that you match all the recommendations given there?

Comment: @yunnosch What in your opinion does not respect the "how to ask" rules ? I would happily edit the post ! Over the years I saw a lot of shitty post that deserved a downvote. But in my opinion this one is kind of ok. Maybe not the best post of the universe but -3 is hard.

Comment: @evan Its really simple. The yellow above and under the button won't go away whatever I do.  Setting margin to 0 for bottom and up has no effet what so ever... I do control the yellow on the left and right with the margin though.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/n08Lcjb/image.png, do you need like this?

Comment: @evan yes that would be great ! Thanks for the help ! I tried wraping the widgets with so many different components but the yellow margin still stays !

Comment: you do not need yellow margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent code.

```
 Widget myWidget() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Container(child: Text("+")),
            )),
        Container(
          height: 100,//i put height
          width: 100,// i put weidth
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: myButton("+")),
        ),
      ])
```

myButton widget :

```
Widget myButton(text) {//remove the margin that not needed
  return new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: new Text(text,
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50.0)),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Its working ! Well done ! Thanks ! I updated fontSize to 40 and height/width to 70/70 to compensate.

Comment: thanks, any problem, you can share me, though you are higher ranking than me.

Comment: This is a code-only answer. Answers with explanation tend to receive more upvotes. What did you change? How does the new code work? Why the old one not? If you explain that, this Q/A becomes useful for future readers, even if they do not have the exactly same problem and have to cherry pick and adapt only the relevant part.

Comment: you need to give height for every parent container. thats it

Comment: Please explain that directly inside the answer, not down here in the comments. Explain how that concept is implemented by the changes you made. For a very long stretch, more words in your explanation make a better explanation. Only very late, explanations get too verbose.